# Php includes and js scripts position

Tags: javascript, php, include

I bought a theme where pages were all HTML with JS scripts loaded at the bottom. I modified the theme and now have PHP files with the following (quite standard, with php includes to load the required content) :

- index.php
- header.php
- menu.php
- footer.php
- content1.php
- content2.php
- content3.php
- ...

All the scripts are still loaded at the end, in footer.php.

My problem lies in the fact that in each content pages I need specific scripts, for exemple content1.php needs script1.js, content2.php needs script2.js...

Here is where I have trouble understanding the proper way of doing it :

I could load all scripts (script1.js, script2,js and script3.js) in the footer therefore whichever content is loaded, the required script will be loaded anyway. But I end up loading scripts that are not being used.

For example, I have a script that generates and displays a table from a json array (which is generated using php and a mysql query). This table is only displayed in content1.php.

I don't want to load this script in the footer as it will then be executed each time a page is displayed even if we don't need it. And I can't include it in content1.php as it requires other scripts (jQuery) which is loaded in the footer, ie. after the php include itself.

Does that make sense ?

Comment: Boooo - no vote ups and no answer accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP conditionals (either an if/else or switch, which might be better) to check the URL value and load the appropriate scripts for the page in header.php. Very rough example below.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($url,'content1') !== FALSE) {
    echo '<script src="script1.js"></script>';
} 
elseif (strpos($url,'content2') !== FALSE) {
    echo '<script src="script2.js"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Used a similar solution to this, with a `switch` on the value of the current page : `$_GET['page']`. It's still a bit confusing as the code is spread over several pages, but works !

Answer (score 0):

Why not load the ones you need more often in the header file i.e. jquery and call the optional files at the bottom of the page where they needed, there by removing all calls from the footer

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off combining the files and including the new file in the footer. One file would result in fewer requests, but keep an eye on the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Done a small thing few years ago as follows:

```
<?php
if(getPageJsname()!='') {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-code-<?php echo getPageJsname(); ?>.js"></script>
<?php
}
?>
function getPageJsname() {
return $scriptname = trim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], "/");
}
```

After this you can rename all the javascript files as follows:

for page content1.php js name will be jquery-code-content1.js

and vice-versa

See if this help with something

Comment: this will help not to loop around for every page you create, just name the js file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take this out of the footer:

`<script></script>`

```
</body>

</html>
```

And put it in each page accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in content1.php create a var

```
$script='script1.js';
```

the same in content2.php

```
$script='script2.js';
```

and content3.php

```
$script='script3.js';
```

finally in footer.php

```
echo '<script src="'.$script.'"></script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, easiest and obvious solution would be to load jQuery before content blocks start. While it is recommended and good to include scripts at the bottom, it's not that of a cornerstone. It is also recommended to combine and compress your JS, so you can generate one compressed JS for all your pages.

But you can also try to load scripts via AJAX after document is rendered. There is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/
And you know what content is loaded by that point.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($("#content1").length > 0) { ... }
    });
```

You can also try to wrap your code in function to postpone it's execution untill jQuery is also loaded.